# Boostrap tab urls on detail screens with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

My BackboneJS app has a detail view, say for a Book, that is represented by url like **editorial/book/edit/4**. The Book view consists of several tabs, based on TwitterBoostrap markup, e.g. tabs General/Special/Admin for a Book.

If I use Boostrap tabs as prescribed in their docs, e.g.

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#special">Special</a></li>
```

then once tab is clicked URL in the address bar becomes invalid, instead of siteurl/editorial/book/edit/4#special it the nav bar displays siteurl#special.

Q1: What's the best way to build a tab with valid url with Backbone/Boostrap? The next step I aim at is to make this view reloadable, e.g. so that when a tab is selected and user hits "Reload" in browser, at least same view is loaded, ideally - with latest tab selected.

Q2: What's the ideal way - to build one router function for all detail screen with its tabs or split into a few router functions per each tab?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to handle the navigation via JS side.

**Answer to question 1**

When a user clicks on the tab, on the handler use the backbone navigate function:

```
app.navigate("siteurl/editorial/book/edit/4" + '#' + tabId, {trigger: true});
```

(This examaple has the URL path hardcoded, just grab it with `document.URL` or another function that fulfill your needs)

**Answer to question 2**

That would depend on the logic you need to implement and if that logic is heavy or not. As in your question you said that each tab has a different view, I would suggest to just split the logic inside one router function as all of they apply to the same path (e.g. siteurl/editorial/book/edit/4) and they just differ in the fragment URL.

```
routes: {
  "siteurl/editorial/book/edit/4#:tabId":         "tab",
}
router.on("siteurl/editorial/book/edit/4#:tabId", function(tabId) {
  //Split your logic based on the tabId
});
```